# Communicating with VM on remote host (How to configure routing)

Tags: ubuntu, routing, virtual-machines, multipass

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Server and am tying to stand up VMs on the server using Multipass. I am able to successfully launch VMs and can ssh to them from the server. However I am unable to establish an ssh session from my laptop and presumably any other traffic.

I followed this post, but haven't picked out any details that will help me yet. Here are some pertinent details I've already attempted with the setup. [How to route all VM traffic through specific physical interface over a Linux bridge?](https://serverfault.com/questions/993898/how-to-route-all-vm-traffic-through-specific-physical-interface-over-a-linux-bri?newreg=9d5ad118b0ec438e8687024f692826cd)

The Multipass VMs are running on subnet `10.23.128.0/24`. My server's IP is `192.168.2.127`. The server's routing table is:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.23.128.0/24 dev mpqemubr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.23.128.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev mpqemubr0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.127 metric 100
```

This is my Multipass bridge configuration:

```
ip addr show mpqemubr0
4: mpqemubr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ed:70:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.23.128.1/24 brd 10.23.128.255 scope global mpqemubr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feed:702e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have created a static route on my router that should route traffic on my 192.168.2.0/24 subnet to 192.168.2.127:

```
$ ip route show table static
10.23.128.0/24 via 192.168.2.127 dev br0
```

When I traceroute from my router, I get:

```
$ traceroute 10.23.128.80
traceroute to 10.23.128.80 (10.23.128.80), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.127 (192.168.2.127)  0.397 ms  0.232 ms  0.281 ms
 2  192.168.2.127 (192.168.2.127)  0.210 ms  0.171 ms  0.176 ms
```

I think I have most everything setup, but I believe I'm missing something on my Ubuntu server. When I check `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` the value is `1`.

I appreciate any assistance that you can provide.